# Play Validation - Custom form field validation with specific field error

Tags: validation, scala, playframework-2.0

```
case class Address(
  address1: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  postal: String,
  country: String
)

Form(
    mapping = mapping(
      "address1" -> nonEmptyText,
      "city" -> nonEmptyText,
      "state" -> nonEmptyText,
      "postal" -> nonEmptyText,
      "country" -> nonEmptyText
    )(Address.apply)(Address.unapply).verifying("Invalid Postal Code!", validatePostal _)
)

def validatePostal(address: Address): Boolean = {
    address.country match {
      case "US" | "CA" =>
        val regex: Regex = ("^(\\d{5}-\\d{4}|\\d{5}|\\d{9})$|^([a-zA-Z]\\d[a-zA-Z]( )?\\d[a-zA-Z]\\d)$").r
        regex.pattern.matcher(address.postal).matches()
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

Above form validation for postal code works fine with global error displayed on form for invalid US or Canadian postal codes.

I would like to show the error as field error right next to the field than as global error which in my case is shown on top of the form.

Is there a way to use inbuilt Form constraints or verification methods to achieve this instead of FormError's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the constraint to the field.  Then update validatePostal to accept a tuple of the two values instead.

```
Form(
  mapping = mapping(
    "address1" -> nonEmptyText,
    "city" -> nonEmptyText,
    "state" -> nonEmptyText,
    "postal" -> tuple(
      "code" -> nonEmptyText,
      "country" -> nonEmptyText
    ).verifying("Invalid Postal Code!", validatePostal _),
  )((address1, city, state, postal) => Address(address1, city, state, postal._1, postal._2))((address: Address) => Some((address.address1, address.city, address.state, (address.postal, address.country))))
)
```

Template:

```
@inputText(
  addressForm("postal.code"), 
  '_label -> "Postal code",
  '_help -> "Please enter a valid postal code.",
  '_error -> addressForm.error("postal")
)
```

Comment: In his validation he uses both postal and country values in validatePostal definition, so I don't think this is a valid solution.

Comment: @Khanser, thanks for pointing that out.  I changed the code above to handle this case.

Comment: If he doesn't care if the error wraps around both code and contry, that's a perfectly valid solution :) Maybe it could be improved using constraints http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCustomValidations So the validation message gets scoped in the constraint validation instead of every form that uses it.

Comment: This still attaches error to postal field and not postal.code field. I show errors right below the field on form and since there is no form input with postal field now, error will not be shown. This boils down to the same scenario as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: You can set the 'error attribute on the postal.code field.  I added an example above.  This also invalidates @Khanser statement about having wrapped an error about code and country.  Keep in mind, the 'help attribute is not needed, but just wanted to show you some additional functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Defining the error like that you are creating a `FormError("","Invalid Postal Code!")` object in a form, as it doesn't have key (the first parameter), the framework don't attach the error to the form element.

On form error when you are binding the request to the form, you will have to create a new form removing the `FormError("","Invalid Postal Code!")` and replacing it with an error `FormError("form.id","message")`

In our project we created an implicit def for Form to replace the form errors (we couldn't find a way to create dynamic constraint validations) these are the 2 definitions we have:

```
def replaceError(key: String, newError: FormError): Form[T] = {
  val updatedFormErrors = form.errors.flatMap { fe =>
    if (fe.key == key) {
      if (form.error(newError.key).isDefined) None
      else {
        if (newError.args.isEmpty ) Some(FormError(newError.key,newError.message,fe.args))
        else Some(newError)
      }
    } else {
      Some(fe)
    }
  }

  form.copy(errors = updatedFormErrors.foldLeft(Seq[FormError]()) { (z, fe) =>
    if (z.groupBy(_.key).contains(fe.key)) z else z :+ fe
  })
}

def replaceError(key: String, message: String, newError: FormError): Form[T] = {
  def matchingError(e: FormError) = e.key == key && e.message == message
  val oldError = form.errors.find(matchingError)
  if (oldError.isDefined) {
    val error = if (newError.args.isEmpty) FormError(newError.key,newError.message,oldError.get.args) else newError
    form.copy(errors = form.errors.filterNot(e => e.key == key && e.message == message)).withError(error)
  }
  else form
}
```

We have those in a class called `FormCryptBind` (because we also improve the form object with some crypto stuff) and we define the implicit def like this:

```
implicit def formBinding[T](form: Form[T])(implicit request: Request[_]) = new FormCryptBind[T](form)
```

We do it like that because just importing the object having this implicit definition, you can use all the `FormCryptBind` definitions as they were Form's

And we use it like this

```
import whatever.FormImprovements._
...
object SomeController extends Controller{
...
def submit = Action{ implicit request =>
form.bindRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => {
    val newForm = formWithErrors.replaceError("", "formField.required", FormError("formField", "error.required")
    BadRequest(someView(newForm)
  },
  formDetails => Redirect(anotherView(formDetails))
}
```

As I can't put actual live code from the app, I touched it a little bit :D so expect compile errors if you copy & paste