# Conditional mapping in play scala

Tags: validation, scala, playframework-2.0

Using play 2.x, I have the following Form mapping:

```
val relocationDtoForm: Form[RelocationDto] = Form(
  mapping(
    "_type" -> text,
    "sourceToken" -> text,
    "exchange" -> optional(jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy")),
    "completion" -> optional(jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy")),
    "expectedMoveIn" -> optional(jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy"))
  )(RelocationDto.apply)(RelocationDto.unapply)
)
```

I would like to add validation so that if _type=="sale", then exchange is a required field, but if _type=="let" then expectedMoveIn is a required field. I cant seem to find a way to  do this with the standard play validators, is there a way to do it?

Cheers
Nic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `verifying` method of `Mapping`. This will allow you to create constraints after the form has been successfully bound to a class, where you can access other fields. It accepts the error message and a boolean function, which will add an error to the form when `false`.

```
val relocationDtoForm: Form[RelocationDto] = Form(
  mapping(
    "_type" -> text,
    "sourceToken" -> text,
    "exchange" -> optional(jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy")),
    "completion" -> optional(jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy")),
    "expectedMoveIn" -> optional(jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy"))
  )(RelocationDto.apply)(RelocationDto.unapply)
  .verifying(
    "Exchange is required for sales.",
     relocationRto => if(relocationRto._type == "sale") relocationRto.isDefined else true
  ).verifying(
    "Expected move in is required for let?",
     relocationRto => if(relocationRto._type == "let") expectedMoveIn.isDefined else true
  )
)
```

Comment: Ah yes i did try this but the problem is that the resulting error will not be bound to the field, it will just be at the form level. I need the field to be marked invalid in the subsequent presentation to the user. Is it possible?

Comment: With form mappings, it doesn't seem so. The form fields don't know anything about each other until they're bound to something. When the validation depends on multiple fields like that, should the error really be bound to one anyway? If you really want to do this it looks like you'll have to validate your object outside the form (once it's been bound), and add the errors yourself using `withError`. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form

Comment: The reason i need to do it is that my form and therefore my dto is multi-purpose, and maps to one of two case-classes. Before i try to do it i need to validate it will map ok (based on _type). So i think there is a case for needing to do this, as you suggest though using manual valiadtion in the controller looks like the way to go for now. Thanks! NFV

Comment: @nfvindaloo You can use LimbSoup's validation mechanism and bind the errors to form elements. I answered this already in another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491242/play-validation-custom-form-field-validation-with-specific-field-error/22492275#22492275

Answer (score 1):

I used to work for Her Majesty's Revenue and Customs (UK) and looks like HMRC have open-sourced a very useful and easy to use library specialising in conditional Play mappings: https://github.com/hmrc/play-conditional-form-mapping

Answer (score 0):

My final solution at long last was:

```
  def save(id: String) = Action { implicit request =>

    //Runs some extra validation based on the _type value
    def typeSpecificValidate(params: Map[String,Seq[String]]): Seq[FormError] = params("_type") match {
      case Seq("sale") => {
        Forms.tuple(
          "exchange" -> jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy"),
          "completion" -> jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy")
        ).bind(params.mapValues(seq => seq.head)) match {
          case Left(errors) => errors    //Bind returns a Left(List(FormErrors)) or a Right(boundTuple)
          case _ => Nil
        }
      }
      case Seq("let") => {
        Forms.tuple(
          "expectedMoveIn" -> jodaDate("dd/MM/yyyy")
        ).bind(params.mapValues(seq => seq.head)) match {
          case Left(errors) => errors    //Bind returns a Left(List(FormErrors)) or a Right(boundTuple)
          case _ => Nil
        }
      }
    }

    val extraErrors = typeSpecificValidate(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get)

    Logger.debug("Custom validator found: " + extraErrors)

    val ff = relocationDtoForm.bindFromRequest
    ff.copy(errors = ff.errors ++ extraErrors).fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        formWithErrors.errors.foreach(e => Logger.debug(e.toString))
        BadRequest(views.html.relocations.detail(id, formWithErrors))
      },
      relocationDto => {
        Logger.debug(relocationDto.toString)
        Ok(views.html.relocations.detail(id, relocationDtoForm.fill(relocationDto)))
      }
    )
  }
```