# Play - Custom validations with custom error message

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I am using the Play framework in Scala to develop a small blog website. I currently have a form (successfully) set up for an easy registration of users. This login page just accepts a username (ie. no password yet), verifies that is of the appropriate length and doesn't exist yet, and adds this user to the database (currently still in memory). Length can be verified using just the basic [form functionality](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaForms), however, the uniqueness of this username required me to use [custom validations](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaCustomValidations).

Now, this all works, except for the custom error message. When a normal form requirement is not fulfilled, an error message is returned and displayed in the *view* (eg. "The minimum length is: 5"). I want to display a similar message when the name is not unique. In the first link I provided there is an example of custom validations which seems to have an argument that represents such custom error message for validations you write of your own. However, this does not display in the view, while the others do.

Current validation code:

```
private val myForm: Form[Account] =
    Form(mapping("name" -> text(3, 24))(Account.apply)(Account.unapply).verifying(
      "Account is not in the DB.",
      fields =>
        fields match {
          case data: Account => accountExists(data.name).isDefined
        }
      )
    )
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: The code of your validation as well as the one of your form might probably help to spot the problem.

Comment: Yes! I've added my current validation code as a snippet :)

Comment: Could also add the form template code?
Or maybe this contains the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491242/play-validation-custom-form-field-validation-with-specific-field-error